# Dynamically add a column with multiple values to any table using a PL/pgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I would like to use a function/procedure to add to a 'template' table an additional column (e.g. period name) with multiple values, and do a cartesian product on the rows, so my 'template' is duplicated with the different values provided for the new column.

E.g. Add a period column with 2 values to my `template_country_channel` table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   unnest(ARRAY['P1', 'P2']) AS prd(period)
     , template_country_channel 
ORDER BY  period DESC
        , sort_cnty
        , sort_chan;

/* 
-- this is equivalent to: 
(
  SELECT   'P2'::text AS period
         , *
  FROM template_country_channel
) UNION ALL ( 
  SELECT   'P1'::text AS period
         , *
  FROM template_country_channel
)
--
*/
```

This query is working fine, but I was wondering if I could turn that into a PL/pgSQL function/procedure, providing the new column values to be added, the column to add the extra column to (and optionally specify the order by conditions).

What I would like to do is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM template_with_periods(
      'template_country_channel'           -- table name
    , ARRAY['P1', 'P2']                    -- values for the new column to be added
    , 'period DESC, sort_cnty, sort_chan'  -- ORDER BY string (optional)
);
```

and have the same result as the 1st query.

So I created a function like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION template_with_periods(template regclass, periods text[], order_by text) 
    RETURNS SETOF RECORD 
AS $BODY$

BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM unnest($2) AS prd(period), $1 ORDER BY $3' USING template, periods, order_by ;


END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
;
```

But when I run:

```
SELECT * 
FROM template_with_periods('template_country_channel', ARRAY['P1', 'P2'], 'period DESC, sort_cnty, sort_chan');
```

I have the error `ERROR: 42601: a column definition list is required for functions returning “record”`

After some googling, it seems that I need to define the list of columns and types to perform the `RETURN QUERY` (as the error message precisely states).
Unfortunately, the whole idea is to use the function with many 'template' tables, so columns name & type lists is not fixed.

- Is there any other approach to try?
- Or is the only way to make it work is to have within the function, a way to get list of columns' names and types of the `template` table?

Comment: *the whole idea is to use the function with many 'template' tables, so columns name & type lists is not fixed* -- that is not a problem: with `RETURNS SETOF RECORD` you need to enlist the column names and types on the calling side, f.ex. `select * from template_with_periods(...) as t(period text, sort_cnty int, sort_chan text)`

Comment: Actually this would mean i have to specify the columns names/types while writing the query, and I would have to know each table structure -- quite tedious, and this is exactly what I want to avoid (if pgsql allows it).

Comment: No, unfortunately, it doesn't allow it. You'll need to define the *exact* structure of your output. Either within the function definition, or (with `RETURNS SETOF RECORD`) at the calling side.

Answer (score 0):

I did this with `refcursor` if You want output columns list completely dynamic:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_record_exists(tablename character varying, columns character varying[], keepcolumns character varying[] DEFAULT NULL::character varying[])
    RETURNS SETOF refcursor AS
$BODY$

DECLARE 
    ref refcursor;
    keepColumnsList text;
    columnsList text; 
    valuesList text;
    existQuery text;
    keepQuery text;
BEGIN
    IF keepcolumns IS NOT NULL AND array_length(keepColumns, 1) > 0 THEN
        keepColumnsList :=  array_to_string(keepColumns, ', ');
    ELSE
        keepColumnsList :=  'COUNT(*)';
    END IF;

    columnsList := (SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(name || ' = ' || value), ' OR ') FROM
        (SELECT unnest(columns[1:1]) AS name, unnest(columns[2:2]) AS value) pair);

    existQuery := 'SELECT ' || keepColumnsList || ' FROM ' || tableName || ' WHERE ' || columnsList;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Exist query: %', existQuery;

    OPEN ref FOR EXECUTE
        existQuery;
    RETURN next ref;
END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then need to call `FETCH ALL IN` to get results. Detailed syntax [here](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/return_result_set_from_stored_procedure) or there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12483222/630169.  Seems it is the only way for now. Hope something will be changed in PostgreSQL 11 with PROCEDURES.