# How to save a postgres query to a file from a remote computer

Tags: bash, postgresql

I have a script which outputs some data from a postgres database:

```
#!/bin/bash

dbname="inventory"
username="postgres"
NOW=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y-%H%M%S")
OUTPUT="output.$NOW"

psql $dbname $username << EOF
\o | cat >> $OUTPUT
select count(*) from component;
select * from product where procode='AAA';
\q
\o
EOF
```

This happily exports the data I need to a text file if I run it on the local machine.

Now I want to do the same thing for 10 remote computers and have the output stored in one file on the machine I run the script from.  I have the following code that will grep some information from the remote machines but I also need to add the postgres data above to my $FILE_OUT below:

```
#!/bin/bash

NOW=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y-%H%M%S")
dbname="inventory"
username="postgres"

echo "Enter the file name"
read FILE_IN
FILE_OUT="invcheck.$NOW"

for i in $(cat $FILE_IN); do
echo $i >> $FILE_OUT

ssh user@$i "ps -efw | grep TRADINGTIMEPLUS /opt/jrms/jrms.ini" >> $FILE_OUT
```

I have tried to put the postgres code in a line like:

```
ssh rmsasi@hj$i "psql $dbname $username << EOF \o | cat >> $FILE_OUT select * from component where code='1000';\q;\o; EOF"
```

but I get errors and the postgres data is not included in the $FILE_OUT

```
psql: warning: extra option o ignored
cat: from: No such file or directory
cat: component: No such file or directory
cat: where: No such file or directory
cat: code=1000: No such file or directory
bash: line 1: q: command not found
bash: line 1: o: command not found
bash: line 1: EOF: command not found
```

I am only new to scripting so hopefully I am just missing something simple.

My thanks in advance and if there is a better way to do what I am trying to achieve I appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Thanks for showing the code first-off without having to be asked :-) .

Comment: `\o | cat >> $OUTPUT` looks odd. Why not just `\o $OUTPUT`? (Edit: DUH, you're appending. Never mind.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`psql`'s `\` commands are terminated by newlines, not semicolons. A bit of a wart IMO.

Because of that you need newlines in your command. Literal newlines are permissible within a quoted literal in the shell, so you could insert them in the command, but it's better to just have your here-document locally and send it to `psql`'s stdin via `ssh`'s stdin. This'll still leave the output on the remote machine, though:

```
ssh rmsasi@hj$i "psql $dbname $username" << __EOF__
 \o | cat >> $FILE_OUT
SELECT * from component where code='1000';
\q
\o
__EOF__
```

It's much better to instead read from `psql`'s stdout or redirect it, rather than using `\o` commands; that way the output comes back down the `ssh` session and you can redirect it locally:

```
echo "SELECT * from component where code='1000';" |\
ssh rmsasi@hj$i >> $FILE_OUT \
  "psql --quiet --no-align --no-readline --tuples-only -P footer=off --no-password $dbname $username"
```

Alternately you could have `psql` connect over the network from the other machines.

Since you're driving `psql` from bash you may want to know that you can do so interactively with [a co-process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8305578/398670). You also don't need to redirect output to a tempfile like that; just suppress `psql`'s printing of prompts and headers (see linked answer) and you can simply read the results from `psql`'s stdout.

Comment: Thanks Craig this solved my issue and I appreciate the extra information - its always nice to have your issue resolved and learn something new.  The cat I picked up from a web site somewhere but I removed it and it worked fine as you suggested.

Comment: @Rob Glad to help. I *love* how powerful ssh is for network scripting.