# Store PostgreSQL query result to Shell or PostgreSQL variable

Tags: postgresql, shell

For instance, I have a table stores value:

```
select * from myvalue;

  val
-------
 12345
(1 row)
```

How can I save this `12345` into a variable in postgresql or shell script?

Here's what I tried in my shell script:

```
var=$(psql -h host -U user -d db <<SQLSTMT
SELECT * FROM myvalue;
SQLSTMT)
```

but `echo $var` gives me:

```
val ------- 12345 (1 row)
```

I've also tried

```
\set var (select * from myvalue)
```

in psql and when I type `\set` it lists:

```
var = '(select*frommyvalue)'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, no, no! Use "raw data" switch from psql, like "-t" or "\t" and pipe the query to psql instead of parsing ascii-table, come on :-)

```
echo 'select * from myvalue;' | psql -t -h host -U user -d db
```

If you really need parse psql output, you could also use -H switch ( turns on HTML output ), and parse it with some perl module for parsing html tables, I used that once or twice.. Also, you may want to use a [pgpass file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html) and [`~/.psqlrc`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#AEN85342) for some defaults, like default DB to connect, when not specified.

Comment: Like @scott-marlowe said, -A removes the table output alignment. Add that flag for a single output.

Answer (score 7):

`psql` has a `-c`/`--command=` option to accept SQL from the command line, and `-t`/`--tuples-only` option to control output formatting.

```
$ psql -c 'select 1+1'
 ?column? 
----------
        2
(1 row)
$ psql -t -c 'select 1+1'
        2

$ VALUE=`psql -t -c 'select 1+1'`
$ echo $VALUE
2
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var=`psql -Atc "select 1;"`
echo $var
1
```

Answer (score 2):

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8305578/398670) I explain one way to do it, using a co-process to communicate back-and-forth with `psql`. That's overkill if all you need is to run a query and get a single result, but might be good to know if you're shell scripting with `psql`.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the result you get with your `psql` command:

```
var=$(psql -h host -U user -d db <<SQLSTMT
SELECT * FROM myvalue;
SQLSTMT)
var=$(cut -d' ' -f3 <<<$var)
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me, but this did:

median_avm=`psql "host=${dps1000} port=#### dbname=@@@ user=${reduser} password=${redpass}" -c "SELECT AVG(column) FROM db.table;" -t`

using a source file with ${dps1000}, ${reduser}, ${redpass} defined and manually entering port and dbname