# store postgresql result in bash variable

Tags: bash, postgresql, variables

How to atore a scalar postgresql-value on a bash-variable like in script below?

```
dbname="testlauf"
username="postgres"

vartest='psql -c -d $dbname -U $username -h localhost -p 5432 "SELECT gid FROM testtable WHERE aid='1';"'
echo "$vartest"
```

I tried several different writings, but nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For command substitution you have to use either backticks (`\``) or `$()`. Single quotes (`'`) won't do.

Comment: Thanks. But even   vartest=`$(psql -c -d testlauf -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 "SELECT gid FROM testtable WHERE aid='1';")`   won't do the trick unfortunatelly... it gives me "sytnac error near or at "-d""  I also tried it with dbname...

Comment: ..somehow it swallows my backsticks in this coammands... but actually i added them before and after 2nd part of the assignment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store PostgreSQL query result to Shell or PostgreSQL variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535766/store-postgresql-query-result-to-shell-or-postgresql-variable)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Put the `-c` option just before its argument - the query. Mind also using the additional `-t` option to get just the tuple value. And of course, use the backticks (**`**) operator.

Using the `-X` option is also recommended, as sometimes a `.psqlrc` file might add some redundant output, as well as the `-A` option, which disables column aligning (whitespaces).

In order to skip NOTICE or other additional messages, include the `-q` flag.

```
vartest=`psql -d $db -U $user -AXqtc "SELECT gid FROM testtable WHERE aid='1'"`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Kouber, this does the trick! Actually backticks still don't seem to work for me, but ($) does: vartest=$(psql -X -h localhost -p 5432 -d testlauf -U postgres -c "SELECT gid FROM testtable WHERE aid='1';")

Comment: How to use dynamic bash script variable or  psql variable in where condition

Comment: Thanks Kouber, is there any option to retain the new line ?

Answer (score 15):

Using -t option or --tuples-only will give you the rows only, so it will easier to store them in array variable (if the result from query more than one)

```
vartest =(`psql -t -d $dbname -U $username -c "SELECT gid FROM testtable WHERE aid='1';"`)
echo $vartest
```

example:

query result

```
ubuntu@ratnakri:~$ psql -h localhost -p 5432 -t -U postgres -d postgres -c "select slot_name from pg_replication_slots"
barman
barman2
```

make it into array variable

```
    ubuntu@ratnakri:~$ RESULT=(`psql -h localhost -p 5432 -t -U postgres -d postgres -c "select slot_name from pg_replication_slots"`)
    ubuntu@ratnakri:~$ echo ${RESULT[0]}
    barman
    ubuntu@ratnakri:~$ echo ${RESULT[1]}
    barman2
```

Comment: how to execute this command on a remote host? How to enter DB password?

Comment: There are several ways to execute on remote host, but for db password, by default postgresql is setup to use peer authentication on unix, just don't specify the -h localhost to use it-