# PostgreSQL - query from bash script as database user 'postgres'

Tags: sql, bash, postgresql

I have a table in my PostgreSQL database which has 3 columns - `c_uid`, `c_defaults` and `c_settings`. `c_uid` simply stores the name of a user and `c_defaults` is a long piece of text which contains a lot of data w.r.t that user.

I have to execute a statement from a bash script which selects the value of the `c_defaults` column based on the `c_uid` value and this needs to be done by the database user 'postgres'.

On the CLI I can do the following:

```
[mymachine]# su postgres
bash-4.1$psql
postgres=#\c database_name
You are now connected to database "database_name" as user "postgres".
database_name=#SELECT c_defaults  FROM user_info WHERE c_uid = 'testuser';
```

However, how do I achieve this through a bash script?

The aim is to get the information from that column, edit it and write it back into that column - all through a bash script.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Try this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
psql -U postgres -d database_name -c "SELECT c_defaults  FROM user_info WHERE c_uid = 'testuser'"
```

Or using `su`:

```
#!/bin/bash
su -c "psql -d database_name -c \"SELECT c_defaults  FROM user_info WHERE c_uid = 'testuser'\"" postgres
```

And also `sudo`:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u postgres -H -- psql -d database_name -c "SELECT c_defaults  FROM user_info WHERE c_uid = 'testuser'"
```

Comment: I ended up using the second one option that you've given and passed it into a variable. Thank you.

Comment: so its -- psql and not --psql ?

Comment: @radtek It's with the space between. You're calling `psql` with `sudo` and `--` is just an optional separator.

Comment: I wrote #!/bin/bash psql -U postgres -d firstdb -c "insert into data value('19*.1*8.1*.** ',32);" psql -c "\q"   But It showed authentication failure

Comment: is there a way to insert a bash variable inside command?

Comment: @postgresnewbie No idea but maybe post a new question.

Answer (score 56):

You can connect to psql as below and write your sql queries like you do in a regular postgres function within the block. There, bash variables can be used. However, the script should be strictly sql, even for comments you need to use -- instead of #:

```
#!/bin/bash
psql postgresql://<user>:<password>@<host>/<db> << EOF
       <your sql queries go here>
EOF
```

Comment: I combined this answer with [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15243971/1494454) to get the perfect solution:
`psql --command="SELECT * FROM table;" postgresql://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<db>`

Comment: what if i have a "@" in my password ?

Comment: I had exactly this issue and never found any answer, so end up with using: `PGPASSWORD=${dbPass} psql -U ${myUsr} -P ....`

Comment: sorry @Jason for late reply. Added below as an answer. -S

Comment: A few weeks ago I came across this question while searching something for my own. The accepted answer helped me solve my problem. Today, after the weeks, your answer solved another problem of mine. SO community is awesome!

Answer (score 18):

if you are planning to run it from a separate sql file. here is a good example (taken from a great page to learn how to bash with postgresql http://www.manniwood.com/postgresql_and_bash_stuff/index.html

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
set -u
if [ $# != 2 ]; then
   echo "please enter a db host and a table suffix"
   exit 1
fi

export DBHOST=$1
export TSUFF=$2
psql \
  -X \
  -U user \
  -h $DBHOST \
  -f /path/to/sql/file.sql \
  --echo-all \
  --set AUTOCOMMIT=off \
  --set ON_ERROR_STOP=on \
  --set TSUFF=$TSUFF \
  --set QTSTUFF=\'$TSUFF\' \
   mydatabase

   psql_exit_status = $?

   if [ $psql_exit_status != 0 ]; then
     echo "psql failed while trying to run this sql script" 1>&2
     exit $psql_exit_status
   fi

   echo "sql script successful"
exit 0
```

Comment: I keep getting psql_exit_status: not found

Answer (score 13):

Once you're logged in as `postgres`, you should be able to write:

```
psql -t -d database_name -c $'SELECT c_defaults FROM user_info WHERE c_uid = \'testuser\';'
```

to print out just the value of that field, which means that you can capture it to (for example) save in a Bash variable:

```
testuser_defaults="$(psql -t -d database_name -c $'SELECT c_defaults FROM user_info WHERE c_uid = \'testuser\';')"
```

To handle the logging in as `postgres`, I recommend using `sudo`. You can give a specific user the permission to run

```
sudo -u postgres /path/to/this/script.sh
```

so that they can run just the one script as `postgres`.

Comment: `-bash-4.1$ psql -t -d database_name $'SELECT c_defaults FROM user_info WHERE c_uid = \'testuser\';'` gives me and error - _"psql: FATAL:  role "SELECT c_defaults FROM user_info WHERE c_uid = 'testuser';" does not exist_
"

Comment: @i.h4d35: Oops, sorry, I'd left out the `-c` flag (introducing the query or command for `psql` to run). I've added it now.

Comment: Key to the solution for me was escaping those pesky single quotes. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

The safest way to pass commands to `psql` in a script is by piping a string or passing a here-doc.

The man docs for the `-c/--command` option goes into more detail when it should be avoided.

```
   -c command
   --command=command
       Specifies that psql is to execute one command string, command, and then exit. This is useful in shell scripts. Start-up files (psqlrc and ~/.psqlrc)
       are ignored with this option.

       command must be either a command string that is completely parsable by the server (i.e., it contains no psql-specific features), or a single
       backslash command. Thus you cannot mix SQL and psql meta-commands with this option. To achieve that, you could pipe the string into psql, for
       example: echo '\x \\ SELECT * FROM foo;' | psql. (\\ is the separator meta-command.)

       If the command string contains multiple SQL commands, they are processed in a single transaction, unless there are explicit BEGIN/COMMIT commands
       included in the string to divide it into multiple transactions. This is different from the behavior when the same string is fed to psql's standard
       input. Also, only the result of the last SQL command is returned.

       Because of these legacy behaviors, putting more than one command in the -c string often has unexpected results. It's better to feed multiple
       commands to psql's standard input, either using echo as illustrated above, or via a shell here-document, for example:

           psql <<EOF
           \x
           SELECT * FROM foo;
           EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case the best solution including the requirement for authentication is:

```
username="admin"
new_password="helloworld"

PGPASSWORD=DB_PASSWORD \
  psql -h HOSTNAME -U DB_USERNAME -d DATABASE_NAME -c \
  "UPDATE user SET password = '$new_password' WHERE username = '$username'"
```

This command will update a password of a user e.g. for recovery case.

**Info:** The trade-off here is that you need to keep in mind that the password will be visible in the bash history. For more information see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14740/how-to-use-psql-with-no-password-prompt?newreg=358e15081da14221ab68c3ffdad3ccfc).

**Update:** I'm running the databse in a docker container and there I just need the commmand: `docker exec -i container_name psql -U postgres -d postgres -c "$SQL_COMMAND"`

Answer (score 1):

To ans to @Jason 's question, in my bash script, I've dome something like this (for my purpose):

```
dbPass='xxxxxxxx'
.....
## Connect to the DB
PGPASSWORD=${dbPass} psql -h ${dbHost} -U ${myUsr} -d ${myRdb} -P pager=on --set AUTOCOMMIT=off
```

The another way of doing it is:

```
psql --set AUTOCOMMIT=off --set ON_ERROR_STOP=on -P pager=on \
     postgresql://${myUsr}:${dbPass}@${dbHost}/${myRdb}
```

but you have to be very careful about the password: I couldn't make a password with a `'` and/or a `:` to work in that way. So gave up in the end.

-S

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
password='complex=!password'
PGPASSWORD=$(echo $password) psql -h example.com -U example_user -d example_db -t -c "select * from example_table1" -o example_out.txt
```

Comment: Answers that contains only links will be delete in future so please post your answers with code and its explanation.

Comment: @JaimilPatel: Was your comment meant for a different post? This answer doesn’t contain a link. (It does, however, only provide code, so it’d certainly benefit from some further explanation.)