# psql shell command execution with \!

Tags: postgresql, shell, psql

Is there any way to capture shell output (in a psql variable) and/or the exit code of running a shell command from inside `psql` using `\!`? The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-psql.html) provides no details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using `\!` with `\i`..

You can combine the two like this,

- `\! echo "SELECT 1;" > bar` (runs the command `echo "SELECT 1;"` redirects output of `SELECT 1;` to `bar`)
- `\i bar` (runs the commands in `bar`)

Comment: @TobiM good catch, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be impossible for `\!`,

but one can set a variable from external command output,

```
testdb=> \set content `cat my_file.txt`
```

and then using this var in sql expression  like this:

```
testdb=> INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (:'content');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `\o <filename>` option to specify the output file or use `COPY` [command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html) to solve your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how `\o` helps. If I am running a shell command, I can always redirect its output to a file. Also not sure how `COPY` helps. I'm not trying to load data.

Comment: well, I guess it depends what you are trying to achieve, for bulk ddl updates I used `\o` a [lot](https://github.com/dsavinkov/shell/blob/master/update_all_postgres_schemas.sh). I guess it's not your case.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535766/store-postgresql-query-result-to-shell-or-postgresql-variable) might be what you are looking for

Comment: The SO question you point to is about capturing SQL output _from_ psql. I want to capture shell output and exit code _in_ psql.

Comment: Well, according to the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-psql.html) you can achieve what you want by capturing in shell exit status and using meta-commands. Why can't you use exit codes ? @Sim

Comment: I can capture the shell exit status of `psql` but I see no documentation for how to capture the exit status of whatever is run via `\!`. Do you?