# bash script to update postgres database

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell, cat, psql

I have some html data stored in text files right now. I recently decided to store the HTML data in the pgsql database instead of flat files. Right now, the 'entries' table contains a 'path' column that points to the file. I have added a 'content' column that should now store the data in the file pointed to by 'path'. Once that is complete, the 'path' column will be deleted. The problem that I am having is that the files contain apostrophes that throw my script out of whack. What can I do to correct this issue??

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/sh
dbname="myDB"
username="username"
fileroot="/path/to/the/files/*"

for f in $fileroot
do
psql $dbname $username -c "
  UPDATE entries
  SET content='`cat $f`'
  WHERE id=SELECT id FROM entries WHERE path LIKE '*`$f`';"
done
```

Note: The logic in the `id=SELECT...FROM...WHERE path LIKE ""` is not the issue. I have tested this with sample filenames in the pgsql environment.

The problem is that when I `cat $f`, any apostrophe in **Edit: the contents of** $f closes the SQL string, and I get a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the single quote escaping issue, a reasonable workaround might be to double the quotes, so you'd use:

```
`sed "s/'/''/g" < "$f"`
```

to include the file *contents* instead of the `cat`, and for the second invocation in the `LIKE` where you appeared to intend to use the file *name* use:

```
${f/"'"/"''"/}
```

to include the literal string content of `$f` instead of executing it, and double the quotes. The `${varname/match/replace}` expression is `bash` syntax and may not work in all shells; use:

```
`echo "$f" | sed "s/'/''/g"`
```

if you need to worry about other shells.

---

There are a bunch of other problems in that SQL.

- You're trying to *execute* `$f` in your second invocation. I'm pretty sure you didn't intend that; I imagine you meant to include the literal string.
- Your subquery is also wrong, it lacks parentheses; `(SELECT ...)` not just `SELECT`.
- Your `LIKE` expression is also probably not doing what you intended; you probably meant `%` instead of `*`, since `%` is the SQL wildcard.

---

If I also change backticks to `$()` (because it's clearer and easier to read IMO), fix the subquery syntax and add an alias to disambiguate the columns, and use a here-document instead passed to `psql`'s stdin, the result is:

```
psql $dbname $username <<__END__
  UPDATE entries
  SET content=$(sed "s/'/''/g" < "$f")
  WHERE id=(SELECT e.id FROM entries e WHERE e.path LIKE '$(echo "$f" | sed "s/'/''/g")');
__END__
```

The above assumes you're using a reasonably modern PostgreSQL with `standard_conforming_strings = on`. If you aren't, change the regexp to escape apostrophes with `\` instead of doubling them, and prefix the string with `E`, so `O'Brien` becomes `E'O\'Brien'`. In modern PostgreSQL it'd instead become `'O''Brien'`.

---

In general, I'd recommend using a real scripting language like Perl with DBD::Pg or Python with psycopg to solve scripting problems with databases. Working with the shell is a bit funky. This expression would be much easier to write with a database interface that supported parameterised statements.

For example, I'd write this as follows:

```
import os
import sys
import psycopg2

try:
        connstr = sys.argv[1]
        filename = sys.argv[2]
except IndexError as ex:
        print("Usage: %s connect_string filename" % sys.argv[0])
        print("Eg: %s \"dbname=test user=fred\" \"some_file\"" % sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(1)


def load_file(connstr,filename):
        conn = psycopg2.connect(connstr)
        curs = conn.cursor()
        curs.execute("""
        UPDATE entries
        SET content = %s
        WHERE id = (SELECT e.id FROM entries e WHERE e.path LIKE '%%'||%s);
        """, (filename, open(filename,"rb").read()))
        curs.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        load_file(connstr,filename)
```

Note the SQL wildcard `%` is doubled to escape it, so it results in a single `%` in the final SQL. That's because Python is using `%` as its format-specifier so a literal `%` must be doubled to escape it.

You can trivially modify the above script to accept a list of file names, connect to the database once, and loop over the list of all file names. That'll be a *lot* faster, especially if you do it all in one transaction. It's a real pain to do that with `psql` scripting; you have to use bash co-process [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8305578/398670) ... and it isn't worth the hassle.

Comment: answered everything I could have possibly wanted to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the original post, I made it sound like there were apostrophes in the filename represented by $f. This was NOT the case, so a simple `echo "$f"` was able to fix my issue.

To make it more clear, the contents of my files were formatted as html snippets, typically something like `<p>Blah blah <b>blah</b>...</p>`. After trying the solution posted by Craig, I realized I had used single quotes in some anchor tags, and I did NOT want to change those to something else. There were only a few files where this violation occurred, so I just changed these to double quotes by hand. I also realized that instead of escaping the apostrophes, it would be better to convert them to `&apos;` Here is the final script that I ended up using:

```sh
dbname="myDB"
username="username"
fileroot="/path/to/files/*"

for f in $fileroot
do
psql $dbname $username << __END__
  UPDATE entries
  SET content='$(sed "s/'/\&apos;/g" < "$f")'
  WHERE id=(SELECT e.id FROM entries e WHERE path LIKE '%$(echo "$f")');
__END__
done
```

The format coloring on here might make it look like the syntax is incorrect, but I have verified that it is correct as posted.