# Insert XML from file in PostgreSQL

Tags: xml, file, postgresql, insert

I have several XML files and want to insert their content into a PostgreSQL table. This table has two columns - id (type serial) and a xml type column, in which I want to insert the content of one xml file (one row, one column = one xml file). In the documentation I haven't found how to insert xml from a file.

Is there some easy way how to do it?

Marek

Comment: What language and client library are you using? PostgreSQL version?

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.0.7. The database will be accessed from php code (php 5.3). Does it mean that there is no simple (built in PostgreSQL) way how to load xml file content into database table column?

Comment: This is usually done by the client software, but I can't think of a simple way doing this with `psql`. Which SQL client are you using?

Comment: I use psql under SUSE linux (SLED) or can use pgAdmin III v1.16.1 under Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Handily I just wrote an example of how to do this with plain text files that'll apply equally well to `xml` files. See the question [updating table rows based on txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15606990/398670).

It turns out you can do this with `psql`:

```
regress=> CREATE TABLE xmldemo(id serial primary key, blah xml);
regress=> \set test = `cat some.xml`
regress=> INSERT INTO xmldemo(blah) VALUES (:'test');
INSERT 0 1
```

If you're doing lots of this you might want to [drive `psql` using a co-process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942632/how-to-extrace-pg-backend-pid-from-postgresql-in-shell-script-and-pass-it-to-ano/8305578#8305578) or at least to generate SQL and pipe it into `psql`'s stdin, so you don't have to do all that connection setup/teardown over and over.

Alternately, doing it with the shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
xmlfilename=$1
sep=$(printf '%04x%04x\n' $RANDOM $RANDOM)
psql <<__END__
INSERT INTO mytable(myxmlcolumn) VALUES (
\$x${sep}\$$(cat ${xmlfilename})\$x${sep}\$
);
__END__
```

The random separator generation is to protect against (unlikely) injection attacks that rely on knowing or guessing the dollar quoting separator tag.

You're going to be *much* saner and happier if you use a proper scripting language and PostgreSQL client library like Perl with `DBI` and `DBD::Pg`, Python with `psycopg2` or Ruby with the `Pg` gem for any non-trivial work. Significant work with databases in the shell leads to pain, suffering, and excessive use of co-processes.

Comment: Another option would be to use SQL Workbench/J which supports an "extended" syntax like: `insert into foo (id, content) values (42, {$clobfile='/foo/bar.xml')`.

Comment: And what about this? If it works with text files, it should work also with xml files http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968039/postgresql-inserting-value-of-a-column-from-a-file?rq=1  I mean the use of \set content `cat file`
INSERT INTO testtable VALUES(15, :'content');