# How to add shell commands while executing psql in shellscript

Tags: shell, psql, coproc

Currently I'm writing a shell script that do batch job on the database and I want to put shell script action like write to log file or rollback in some condition while executing psql.
Like this

```html
ConnectDb() {
  PGPASSWORD=postgres psql -U postgres database -t -A -F , -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -v AUTOCOMMIT=0
}

printMsg() {
 echo "$PROGRAM/$SUBMODULE $(date "+ %Y%H%s")" $1 | tee -a ~/Desktop/shell/log/test.log
}

ConnectDb <<EOF
  start transaction;
  select * from ...;
  # do some database stubs here
  
  # i want to add somthing like this
  printMsg "Querying ..."
  # many shell script command go here
  if [ some accepted condition ] commit;
  if [ some bad conditions ] rollback;
  if [ should do more database query ] do insert, update, delete to database
  
  
  commit;
EOF
```

Is there any way to retrieve that?

UPDATE
use coprocess should work perfectly.
For those who met the same problem
[UNIX Co process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86270/how-do-you-use-the-command-coproc-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`psql` doesn't really have any sort of flow control, so no. You can use the `\!` command to run shell, but since you can't make flow control decisions based on it it won't help you.

Instead, invert control. Have your shell script control `psql` and make decisions based on `psql` output. Run `psql -qAtX` so you only get tuple output.

Usually just running `psql` a bunch times is enough, but for more complex cases you can [run it as a coprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7942632/398670). I find that by that point it starts getting more useful to script from a language where you can integrate queries better, like `python3`'s `psycopg2`.

Comment: coprocess seems the best option for me but when i change the connect to coproc PGPASSWORD=postgres psql -U postgres database -t -A -F , -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -v AUTOCOMMIT=0 -q. When i run the bash the terminal said coproc not found but coproc work if run directly in terminal. What setup should i do here?

Comment: Thank you, the reason is my bash version does not support coproc (v3.2), since apple does not update sh so  use zsh or ksh should work perfectly. Thank you a lot. It safe me a day